# Is there a function to download Quicksight dashboards as pdf?

Tags: boto3, amazon-quicksight

Is there a way to export a Quicksight dashboard via API, (Via console it's Export > Download as pdf) ? I checked the boto3 docs and couldn't find it, so would appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 1):

We recently had a meeting with some representatives of the AWS Quicksight team who confirmed:

> PDF export is only possible through QuickSight console, no api
> functionality